# What security concept should I add to protect my game server that run UDP socket?

Tags: sockets, server, tcp, udp, game-development

My android client first connect to my python server via TCP connection and get an ID from the server. Afterwards, player send messages to UDP socket along with that ID to play the game.

I don't think this will be safe since there is no security concept or tool here. Anybody can connect and keep sending requests since they know the server ip and this may cause attacks like DoS or some kind of other problems I ain't overseen due to lack of knowledge.

I am currently checking the messages coming to UDP socket with looking both **IP** and **ID** that I've sent to the player. If no such user exists then I don't proceed the message.
I am also having a list of banned IP's and if a person keep sending unrelated messages I add their IP and blocking/closing their connection due to having a certain message format/structure in the client side. These two are the only things that I do.

But you see, this doesn't help about my case because still anyone can write a script and easily start to keep sending many requests from different devices to my UDP socket.

How do I avoid attacks to my server or should I be worried in this case?

Comment: "*How do I avoid attacks to my server*" - put it behind a good firewall